# Making calculations from nested arrays in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$scope.products = [
  {
    nom : "Pa de fajol",
    img : "dill1.jpg",
    descripcio: [
      "Pa de motlle"
    ],
    preu:4.90,
    tipus: "Pa"
  },
  {
    nom : "Pagès semi integral de blat/espelta",
    img : "dill2.jpg",
    descripcio: [
      "Pa de pagès",
      "680g / 400g"
    ],
    tipus: "Pa",
    variacions : [
      {
        nom: "Gran",
        preu: "3.70",
        grams: "680g",
        basket: 0
      },
      {
        nom: "Petit",
        preu: "2.30",
        grams: "400g",
        basket: 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

In the frontend I display it with an `ng-repeat` and depending if the product has price (preu) or not, I display one input for quantity for single product, or one input for each variation.

Looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="pa in products">
  <div ng-if="!pa.preu" ng-repeat="vari in pa.variacions">
    <input type="number" ng-model="pa.variacions.basket" ng-init="pa.variacions.basket=0">
  </div>
  <input ng-if="pa.preu" type="number" ng-model="pa.basket" name="basket" ng-init="pa.basket=0">
</div>
<a ng-click="insert()">Add to cart</a>
```

When I trigger `insert()`, I have a function that will add the products and calculate the total price, but so far it only works for products with a price, not for the variations.

The function looks like this:

```
$scope.insert = function() {
  $scope.singleorder = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++)
    if($scope.products[i].basket) { // if input has been setted
      $scope.singleorder.push({
        'product': $scope.products[i].nom,
        'number': $scope.products[i].basket,
        'preu': ($scope.products[i].preu * $scope.products[i].basket)
      });
    }
  console.log($scope.singleorder);
}
```

How would I have to proceed to include in the `$scope.singleorder` array also the calculations from the nested array of variations?

Any tips?

## EDIT

See [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/5fJz5GTKcIAoO0oXXPIH?p=preview) to reproduce the issue

## SOLUTION

I managed to fix it with the help of some comments!

See Plunkr for final version. 
Here's the final function:

```
$scope.insert = function() {
  $scope.singleorder = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++)
    if($scope.products[i].basket) { // if input has been setted
      $scope.singleorder.push({
        'product': $scope.products[i].nom,
        'number': $scope.products[i].basket,
        'preu': ($scope.products[i].preu * $scope.products[i].basket)
      });
    }
    else if($scope.products[i].variacions) { // if input has been setted
      angular.forEach($scope.products[i].variacions, function(variacions) {
        if(variacions.basket) {
          $scope.variname =  $scope.products[i].nom + ' (' + variacions.nom + ')'  
          $scope.singleorder.push({
            'product': $scope.variname,
            'number': variacions.basket,
            'preu': (variacions.preu * variacions.basket)
          });
        }
      });
    }

  console.log($scope.singleorder);
```

Comment: can you reproduce this in a plnkr/jsfiddle/jsbin?

Comment: where in your insert function are handling the variations?

Comment: @CallumLinington see edit

Comment: @putonspectacles that's the thing, I don't know how to access them, do the calculations and include them in the final array (singleorder)

Comment: Well, you know how to use the dot syntax, so what's in `$scope.products[i].variacions`?  Probably an array. So loop over that just like you did with `$scope.products`.

Comment: It returns  Cannot read property 'variacions' of undefined

Comment: well not all products have variations (that's why you're getting the error), so before you access check if it has the variations property.

Comment: @putonspectacles that helped! See edited Plunker. Now it adds the object, but some properties are undefined. Also, inputs in the variations share the model, and I don't really understand why...

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was that your **variacions** is an array use this,

```
$scope.insert = function() {
      $scope.singleorder = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++)
        if($scope.products[i].basket) { // if input has been setted
          $scope.singleorder.push({
            'product': $scope.products[i].nom,
            'number': $scope.products[i].basket,
            'preu': ($scope.products[i].preu * $scope.products[i].basket)
          });
        }
        else if($scope.products[i].variacions) { // if input has been setted
          for(var j=0;j<$scope.products[i].variacions.length; j++){
            $scope.singleorder.push({
            'product': $scope.products[i].variacions[j].nom,
            'number': $scope.products[i].variacions[j].basket,
            'preu': ($scope.products[i].variacions[j].preu * $scope.products[i].variacions[j].basket)
          });
          }
        }

      console.log($scope.singleorder);

    }
```

See [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NmQhHHmn0WfbCZei4fE4?p=preview)